# Estimating the Round-Trip Time

Tags: networking

I'm confused about the measurement of RTT in a textbook which says:

**The sample RTT, denoted SampleRTT, for a segment is the amount of time
between when the segment is sent (that is, passed to IP) and when an acknowledgment
for the segment is received. Instead of measuring a SampleRTT for every
transmitted segment, most TCP implementations take only one SampleRTT measurement
at a time. That is, at any point in time, the SampleRTT is being estimated
for only one of the transmitted but currently unacknowledged segments, leading to a
new value of SampleRTT approximately once every RTT.**

I'm confused, it said that TCP doesn't measure a SampleRTT for every transmitted segment, if you don't measure for every segment, how do you get the average time of RTT? And it said that SampleRTT is being estimated for only one of the transmitted but currently unacknowledged segments, doesn't it still sound like it is still measuring every segment (if acked successfully later)

Comment: Which textbook is this? In Linux the smoothed RTT (SRTT) is a EWMA over individual RTT measurements, one per ack.

Comment: Computer networking : a top-down approach / James F. Kurose, Keith W. Ros

Comment: I do not find the 'Estimating the Round-Trip Time' section credible because they do not use known terms such as SRTT and RTTVAR. My advice is to look at RFCs for specific details on how TCP works.

Comment: Not sure what is a SampleRTT, but as mentioned by others, it's probably the SRTT for example